# Возвести число в степень

Tags: c++, c, функции, математика

На строку:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)theCountVector.size(); i++)
    pow((int)theCountVector[i], (int)i);
```

ругается:

```
1>d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(241): error C2668: pow: неоднозначный вызов перегруженной функции
```

Что делать? Заголовок math.h подключен.

Comment: double pow (double base, double exponent);  
float pow (float base, float exponent);  
long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);  
double pow (Type1 base, Type2 exponent);

Нет pow с одними int.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо, первый параметр должен быть плавающим.

Comment: @perfect Просто для информации: 2*2=4, pow(2,2) = 3.999999999... это из личного опыта. Поэтому если требуется возводить в целочисленную степень предпочитаю делать это или множественным умножением само на себя до 5-6 степени, или циклом.